# BGE logic editor won't play action

Tags: animation, game-engine, node-editor

In blender game engine i have a main menu scene with 2 buttons and the main menu board,with surroundings. 
I have set up an action for the main menu to slide (rotation)(Main menu slide) and saved as an action.

I have a:
sensor: Mouse over and mouse click - controller: and - actuator: Action(cube action) and Action(main menu slide)

when i click on the button it applies Action(main menu slide) on the button instead of the main menu.
So the question is... how do i apply this action by clicking the button without the action affecting the button instead of the original saved action?
(i would add blender file but idk how to add a file to this specific online help page)

Answer (score 1):

Actuators **always** operate on the object they belong to.

That means you need to activate the actuator at the main menu rather than the one at the button.

In your situation it might be worth to send a message (when the button gets clicked). The main menu should listen to that message to play the action. Use a unique subject to allow other messages with other purposes.

I hope it helps